# Setting CPU-based timers on macOS

Tags: c, linux, macos, timer

On Linux, the following code can be used to send a SIGVTALRM after 1 second of cpu time has elapsed:

```
timer_t timer;
timer_create(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, NULL, &timer);
struct itimerspec second;
second.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
second.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
second.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
second.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
timer_settime(timer, 0, &second, NULL);
```

How do I do the same thing on macOS? The `timer_create`/`timer_settime` API doesn't exist on macOS, and I can't use `setitimer` since I need to be able to set an unlimited number of timers.